# How to create internal ctor in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create a internal ctor for class in ActionScript3 to make it immutable. I want that only another builder class will be allow to create instances of this immutable class.
I try to find the answer in [Adobe's ActionScrtip 3 specification](http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=as3_specification.html) but it does not explain what happen when no public namespace (accessible) is define for ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable object:

```
package {

    public class Immutable {
        private var _value1:int;
        private var _value2:int;
        private var _value3:int;

        public function Immutable(value1:int, value2:int, value3:int) {
            _value1 = value1;
            _value2 = value2;
            _value3 = value3;
        }

        public function get value1():int {
            return _value1;
        }

        public function get value2():int {
            return _value2;
        }

        public function get value3():int {
            return _value3;
        }
    }
}
```

As for access modifiers, [internal is default](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f32.html).

> The internal attribute is similar to the default access control in Java, although in Java there is no explicit name for this level of access, and it can be achieved only through the omission of any other access modifier. The internal attribute is available in ActionScript 3.0 to give you the option of explicitly signifying your intent to make a property visible only to callers within its own package.

As for constructor, you can't specify internal. If you omit access modifier, by default constructor will be accessible (public)